# Kentico Widgets :: Matching fields with HTML structure of Web Part

Tags: kentico

I really hope I'm making sense with this one.
I'm trying to create a widget from a custom webpart that I created. It's nothing special at all as you can see:

```
<h3>Header</h3>
<p>Intro Copy</p>
<ul>
    <li>List item one</li>
    <li>List item two</li>
    <li>List item three</li>
</ul>
```

I now want to be able to create a widget from this and create new fields that will be used to populate the above DOM. What do I need to do in order or do this.

In an example I saw for the demo site, they populated the bg image with:

**style="background-image: url('{% ResolveUrl(PathToImage) %}');"**

That was however done on the front facing part of the CMS and I'm trying to do it within the solution.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

It's all in your layout or code behind.  Your layout can have that code (but in ASCX format) and it will work just fine.  OR you can add literal controls to the page based on the fields and what the user has entered.

Doing it in your layout is more restrictive and specific to that one application but allows you to use multiple new webpart layouts.  Using the code approach allows you to be more dynamic but doesn't allow you to use the built-in layouts of the webpart/widget.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use the Transformable Web Part in the Marketplace...it does exactly what you want it to do.  Create a custom web part, and you use a Transformation to style the Web Part Properties into the DOM elements.

https://devnet.kentico.com/marketplace/web-parts/transformable-web-part

Reason why i built it!

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar in the past, using what I call *generic web parts*.  I wrote a blog on it last year - it might help out with what I think you're trying to achieve:

http://www.mattnield.co.uk/Posts/Show/generic_web_parts_for_rapid_development

Answer (score 0):

Why are you choosing to go with Widgets? If you want to access any field inside the transformation within the web part it's feasible by the same way as you define in inbuilt web parts.

If you want to perform any function like onload etc. then you need to use kentico API to access any data.

If you provide more insight on what is required, I can help further

Comment: Hi Mani, I'm fairly new to Kentico and I'm trying to figure this out as I go along. Basically I am looking to replicate the Dancing Goat - Text with background widget. That is my goal.

Comment: I am creating this system for both developers as well we in-house end users, and I need to make sure the interface is as user friendly as possible. My back-end knowledge isn't the best either as I am a front-ender

Comment: you can do it with zone layout define a wrapper div and add a editable image web part and editable text. On the editable image associate a class in configuration section which can make the image positioning as background.